# How to select matches separately from xml by xpath on macOS

Tags: xml, macos, xpath, xmllint

I want to get all text contents from an XML file matching some selector.

I chose to use XPath selector because I already have xmllint installed on my Mac (but it is older than version 20909 which apparently has the behaviour I want by default)

```
$ xmllint --version
xmllint: using libxml version 20904
   compiled with: Threads Tree Output Push Reader Patterns Writer SAXv1 FTP HTTP DTDValid HTML Legacy C14N Catalog XPath XPointer XInclude ICU ISO8859X Unicode Regexps Automata Expr Schemas Schematron Modules Debug Zlib
```

Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>
  <foo bar="baz">Lorem</foo>
  <foo bar="baz">Ipsum</foo>
  <foo bar="baz">Dolor</foo>
  <foo bar="qux">Sit</foo>
  <foo bar="baz">Amet</foo>
</xml>
```

I want to get each text content of foo elements that have a certain attribute value

```
$ xmllint --xpath '//foo[@bar="baz"]/text()' my.xml
LoremIpsumDolorAmet
```

The output is not newline-delimited, nor does it seem to be NUL-delimited:

```
$ xmllint --xpath '//foo[@bar="baz"]//text()' my.xml | od -A n -t x1
           4c  6f  72  65  6d  49  70  73  75  6d  44  6f  6c  6f  72  41
           6d  65  74
```

---

How can I present the output such that matches are separated from each other by a newline, using macOS?

Comment: I tried `xmllint` on Ubuntu ("xmllint: using libxml version 20910") and the output is four lines with each word on one line.

Comment: @MartinHonnen it looks like the macos version is outdated

Comment: It seems it is an older version but I can't tell whether the output difference you have is due to that version. Perhaps some other Mac users can test and tell. Do you also have xmlstarlet installed? It has similar selection options, perhaps it gives you a result with several lines.

Comment: Using [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php) the following command gives you a result with several lines: `xml sel -t -v "//foo[@bar='baz']" my.xml`. Alternatively consider using `xsltproc`, _(a command line tool built-in on macOS )_ with an XSLT stylesheet as per [this example](https://paste.ee/p/tJFNe) bash script.

Comment: For reference, I added newlines [in this commit](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/-/commit/da35eeae5b92b88d8ebdb64b4b327ac1c2cf1bce). The first subsequent release was 2.9.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with `xpath --shell` as follows.
If XML file is not too big, it can be optimized to load it in memory.

```
cnt=$(xmllint --xpath 'count(//foo[@bar="baz"])' test.xml)
(for i in $(seq 1 $cnt); do echo "cat //foo[@bar='baz'][$i]/text()"; done) | xmllint --shell test.xml | grep -Ev '\/ [<>]( cat)?| -------'
```

Result:

```
Lorem
Ipsum
Dolor
Amet
```

Without the `grep` at the end it produces

```
/ > cat //foo[@bar='baz'][1]/text()
 -------
Lorem
/ > cat //foo[@bar='baz'][2]/text()
 -------
Ipsum
/ > cat //foo[@bar='baz'][3]/text()
 -------
Dolor
/ > cat //foo[@bar='baz'][4]/text()
 -------
Amet
/ >
```

A different version worth adding to the answer

```
cnt=4; (for i in $(seq 1 $cnt); do echo "cd //foo[@bar='baz'][$i]/text()"; echo "cat"; done) | xmllint --shell test.xml | grep -Ev ' > (cat|cd)?'
```

Without the `grep`

```
/ > cd //foo[@bar='baz'][1]/text()
text > cat
Lorem
text > cd //foo[@bar='baz'][2]/text()
text > cat
Ipsum
text > cd //foo[@bar='baz'][3]/text()
text > cat
Dolor
text > cd //foo[@bar='baz'][4]/text()
text > cat
Amet
text >
```